# Participating in a Minyan with 10th Katan (underage)

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

When given an Aliyah in a shul that uses a katan as the tenth "man" of the minyan, which is contrary to the opinion of the vast majority of gedolei haposkim (SA 55:4), what should one do? Simply refuse? Maybe walk out to save them from blessings in vain?

Is one permitted to refuse to attend a minyan where they occasionally use a katan, as one does not wish to jeopardize his tefilla b'tzibbur?

Comment: Is there anything specific about this case that leads you to ask about it, or would you be satisfied with a generic question about joining a minyan where you disagree with their counting methods?

Comment: There's a debate as to whether a person is required to pray with a minyan. However, I don't think anyone states that when one is asked to join a minyan, he must do so. I.e., one may refuse to comprise a minyan for whatever reason whatsoever and go to another minyan. No explanation required.